# Toopher API: What does the message "Not a valid OAuth signed request" mean?

Tags: api, oauth, toopher

I'm trying to get Toopher working with SSH, and I'm running into this error:

```
Not a valid OAuth signed request.  See http://oauth.net to learn more.
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: It was a virtual machine timing error. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a generic error that indicates that the OAuth signature that was submitted with your request does not match the signature that the Toopher API expected.  Because OAuth is a relatively complex protocol, there are several reasons that this can happen.  The error is intentionally vague about exactly what is wrong with the request to prevent an attacker from using the error message to gain knowledge that could be used to get unauthorized access to the API.

Since it can be difficult to correctly construct OAuth requests, Toopher provides [provided API libraries for many common languages](https://github.com/toopher) to help developers easily make valid requests against the API.  If you're not using one of those libraries, then you should definitely try that first.

If you are already using one of the Toopher-provided libraries, then the next thing to do is make sure your API credentials (Key and Secret) are valid.  You can check your credentials at the ["My Requesters"](https://dev.toopher.com/requesters/) page on Toopher's Developer Portal.

If you still have OAuth problems, then your system clock is probably inaccurate - OAuth incorporates the current system time into the request so that the receiving server can guarantee that a request is not too old.  If the problem goes away when you synchronize your system clock with a known-good time source such as one of [NIST's Network Time Servers](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi), then this is almost certainly the problem.

If your system time becomes skewed again and requests start failing (such as can happen if you're running inside of a virtual machine that doesn't synchronize system time with the hypervisor system), you might need to set up a scheduled task to re-synchronize your system time with the network time server on a regular interval.

Full disclosure: I am a developer at Toopher